# After updating xamarin forms my project is extremely laggy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recently updated my Xamarin to try out the previewer. On the project I am currently working on I updated the needed xamarin forms versions to try it out and now the project is extremely laggy and it is very painful to write code because it laggs a ton. The previewer seems to work even though it laggs a lot but it crashes.

The project itself is kinda big and if I recall i think i even had some minor laggs before i updated xamarin also.

Is there any setting that can decrease this lagg somehow or is my computer (macbook pro 2015) not good enough? If the best solution is to get back to a xamarin version without the previewer, do I need to reinstall Xamarin or is there a setting where I can change it straight away?

Answer (score 0):

It is might be better to check the error log to see what's exactly issue it is happening on your PC. I would suggest either check the visual studio log or check your log at your computer. For example, PC is C:\Users{UserAccount}\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\14.0